# Gradle AspectJ plugin issue

Tags: gradle, spring-aspects

I am facing a major issue with my Spring application since I migrated from Maven to Gradle: aspectj no longer works.

For instance classes annotated with `@Configurable` (which rely on aspectj) don't get their dependencies injected.

In order to replace the `aspectj-maven-plugin`, I tried using this plugin: [from spring security code base](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy) but it seems it is not compatible with Gradle 2.1...

I also tried applying the solution described here: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/working-gradle-spring-aspects to no avail.

**I am just curious to know how people who use Gradle + Spring manage to leverage aspectj...**

Can anyone please kindly advise?